# convert string to timestamp in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to convert string to timestamp in MySQL?

For example I have string 01-05-2016 10:22 am which needs to be fetch with order by desc .

is it possible to sort that ?

Comment: What date is that? Is that the 1st of May or the 5th of January?

Comment: My database data type in varchar .. it fetch like 02-26-2015 10:40 am in order_date field .. i want to sort that field desc .. how to ?

Comment: Best option is for you to change from a varchar to a date/time datatype; then you can just apply a simple ORDER BY clause

Comment: not possible .. the requirement is store data as this format ( mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm a )  and fetch order by desc

Comment: @G Roy - Then you should be saying that the requirement is bad..... what is the business justification for treating strings as dates instead of using actual dates?

Answer (score 0):

use order by function in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table_name order by datetime DESC;
```

this will return values in descending order to php.
no need to be sorted again.

Answer (score 0):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP` does the trick.

and

If you want to use the AM/PM notation, you will need to use `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE(' 2016-05-01 10:22 am', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
);
```

Comment: ..its not working with 
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    STR_TO_DATE(' 2016-05-01 10:22 am', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i%p')
);